# Meaning of "failure on the part of loved ones to act"

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is the context I saw the phrase in:

> Some people say that suicide is a result of cowardice or **failure on the
>   part of loved ones to act**, but those people are, to use the clinical term,
>   fucking idiots;

What does this phrase mean?

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? Is it the meaning of the noun _failure?_ Is it the meaning of the phrase _on the part of?_ Please use the **[edit]** link to add to your question a short summary of the research you have done on your own. For instance, what dictionary did you use to learn about the noun _failure?_ Knowing this will help us provide a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks for respond. I know every single words' definition but cannot get what the sentence want to tell. May you please define this sentence in other words which I understand?

Comment: Did you consult your dictionary to learn what _"on their part"_ means in English? What English dictionary do you use?

Comment: LDOCE Failure: a lack of success in achieving or doing something

Comment: The Longman's dictionary also provides a definition of the usage "on the part of": see [**this link**.](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/on-somebody-s-part-on-the-part-of-somebody) After reading these entries in your dictionary, what do _you_ think _"failure on the part of loved ones to act"_ means?

Comment: How people who we love feel about failure? I'm not sure!

Comment: I encourage you to _read and think about_ the definitions provided in the Longman's dictiionary. They are correct, and the answer to your question lies in your understanding of those dictionary entries.

Comment: failure on the opinion of the people who we love? Means people who we love feels like we are a failure? Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to break down the phrase "failure on the part of loved ones to act" into its subparts and their meanings:

- **Failure:** this word has its normal dictionary meaning of "lack of success,"
- **On the part of:** this can be replaced with the word "by," which has the
  same meaning,
- **Loved ones:** usually means family and/or close friends,
- **To act:** means "to do something" or "do something about it."

So you could rewrite this phrase as follows and keep the same meaning:

> Failure by friends and family to do something.